# How to refer to a Kohain with suspended privileges in prayer

Tags: tefilla, names, kohen-priest

When a Kohain chas v'Shalom marries a divorcée or convert, halacha requires us to suspend his privileges - he may not receive the first aliyah during the Torah reading, duchen, etc, until such time as he divorces.

While the disqualifying situation persists, how do we refer to such a Kohain in prayer for his health? Should he be referred to as "Yonathan Ben Leah HaKohain" as would normally befit a Kohain, or just "Yonathan Ben Leah"?

Comment: Is 'HaKohain' supposed to be added when naming the person in a Mi Shebeirach? I know that certain things (i.e. a title like Harav) are not supposed to be said during a Mi Shebeirach, for some reason like there are no titles before G-d. (Yes, I'm aware people do say titles in Mi Shebeirachs, but I believe that is in error). I'll see if I can find a source for this, who knows, maybe it mentions 'HaKohain' as well.

Comment: @Salmononius2 You mean like this Ram"a? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%98#%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%96

Comment: As long as he is married to her, he is referred to as a *challal* just as their children are. Once he divorces her, he is no longer a *challal*.

Comment: @WAF Similar idea, but not exactly what I was referring to. I'm fairly certain I've seen the idea explicitly mentioned with regards to naming a person in a Mi Shebeirach.

Comment: @sabbabillel temporary classification as a *challal* makes intuitive sense on some level; do you have  a source for that?